# How to set the "start point" and "end point" of a video in google slide by using google script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

How to set the "start point" and "end point" of a video in google slide by using google script?

I've already checked the [document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/video) for video class of Apps Script, and didn't found any way to achieve my purpose.

Can someone please help?

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHi82.png) shows how to set start/end point to the videi in slide UI.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to control the time of a video using Apps Script. The feature is relatively new in the UI as the blog mentions https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2020/10/new-video-playback-option-google-slides.html

That sounds good tho, you can fill out a feature request on https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support#missing_features